# Cardinality of Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am confused about this question, i dont know where to start.

If $A$ is countably infinite and $A - B$ is finite. What is the Cardinality of $A\cap B$?

Can you please give me a hint how to start and the receipe how i can solve such kind of questions.

Comment: **Hint** (with a grain of salt) **:** $|A|=|A-B|+|A\cap B|\implies |A\cap B|=|A|-|A-B|=\_\_\_$.

Comment: I am completly lost. I am figuring out how you came to this equation :(

Comment: Do you understand the motivation for the left-hand side of $\implies$?

Comment: I guess that the Cardinality of A is |A−B|+|A∩B| because it contains A - B and A ∩ B. The problem i have, i cant see one-to-one correspondence between |A| ⟹|A∩B|

Comment: See [Inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: It is even true that $A\cap B=A-(A-B)$ as sets (rather than as cardinalities). If you remove a finite set from a countably infinite set, how much is left?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The cardinality of $A\cap B$ is either finite or countably infinite (why?).

If $A\cap B$ was finite, since $A- B$ is finite, what kind of cardinality would $(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)$ have? What does $(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)$ equal to?

Find a contradiction.

Comment: Oh thank you sooo much. I didnt know abt Inclusion-exclusion principle :) helped me alot to understand it all :D thanks again

Comment: @Zaghi Please, don't misunderstand me, the inclusion-exclusion principle was just a motivation for my hint in the comments. It isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Recall that $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)$, and this is a disjoint union. If $A$ is infinite, then at least one of these sets must be infinite. Also, an infinite subset of a countable set is countable.